# Not able to compile bitcoin core on VS 2022

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, compiling

VS is not able to detect some .hpp files from the boost library. Some files have the following header file calls :

```
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/indexed_by.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/tag.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
```

These files are stored in my C:\Users\pachu\boost\libs\multi_index directory. Even after adding it as an additional include directory the compiler still gives the error while building :

```
2>E:\bitcoin\src\txmempool.h(25,10): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp': No such file or directory
```